# Grafana not working for Message Hub on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, grafana, message-hub

I'm trying to monitor messages on Bluemix Messsage Hub using Grafana but both graphs 'Bytes In' and 'Bytes out' do not show anything and says 'no datapoint'.
The only graph that I'm able to view is 'randomWalk'....
Is there a way to see the number of messages, the offset, or something showing the activity of kafka in and out?

F.G.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed. Let us know if you still have difficulties seeing your Message Hub metrics in Grafana.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently a problem between the Message Hub metrics data collection and the Grafana system.

We're working to get it fixed as soon as possible.